# Buttons that affect a function - PHP

Tags: php, function, button

Scenario:
I am trying to have a part of my page constently run a function, the function is then affected when the above buttons are clicked.
The buttons call functions that are within the main/constant function; master($selected).

Here is what i have tried.
index.php:

```
<? session_start();
require("inc.ini.php");

?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Buttons to funtions</title>
</head>

<body>
    <main>
        <header>
                <form method="post"  action="<?=$_SERVER['php_self']?>">
                    <button type="submit" name="change" value="insert, <?$selected = "func1";?>">Func 1</button>
                    <button type="submit" name="change" value="insert, <?$selected = "func2";?>">Func 2</button>
                </form>
        <!--
        I want to press a button and when it is pressed it calls the function selected and gives it the value of which the button represents.
        -->
        </header>
        <figure>
            <?
            if($_POST['change']){
                echo $selected;
                master($selected);
            }
            ?>
        </figure>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

inc.ini.php:

```
<? session_start();

function master($selected){
    if($selected == "func1"){
        function func1(){
            echo "func 1";
        }
    }
    if($selected == "func2"){
        function func2(){
            echo "func 2";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Another side question. do i need to do these if statements, can the $selector jump straight to the new function.

Comment: You will need javascript and ajax here it seems...or to rename submit buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Php is a server side language, this means that a request needs to be sent to the server to make your code run.

Also when a form submits all of it's children are sent, so it is not possible to distinguish which has been clicked.

That being said:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    require("inc.ini.php");
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Buttons to funtions</title>
</head>

<body>
    <main>
        <header>
                <form method="post"  action="<?=$_SERVER['php_self']?>">
                    <button type="submit" name="change" value="Func1">Func 1</button>
                </form>
                <form method="post"  action="<?=$_SERVER['php_self']?>">
                    <button type="submit" name="change" value="Func2">Func 2</button>
                </form>
        </header>
        <figure>
            <?php
                if (isset($_POST['change'])) {
                    echo $_POST['change'];
                    master($_POST['change']);
                }
            ?>
        </figure>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

If you use 2 forms then you get different values for the same name.

Looking at your inc.ini.php file it seems you're defining functions based on which input has been entered. I would suggest not doing this but if your heart is set on it then okay.

Please add a comment to this post if you need more help.

Hope this helps.

Comment: okay, what would you advise for what i want to do? Basically im making a site to learn PHP, it's based around loading a libary of games i create, into the one page.

Comment: Well it depends. What is the actual result you want from this piece of code? What do you want this to do?

Comment: I just want to to make a new game(the one selected via the button) to load into a figure